# Software to make windows switch to 2nd WiFi signal if 1st one had internet failure

Tags: windows, wifi

I have 2 internet connections BroadBand (BB) & backup (3G from mobile using hotspot) for my windows computer. I want to keep using BB until internet disconnects from there in which case switch to backup 3g while keeping an eye on BB and switching back to it if the internet comes back.

Is there any application like smart wifi or something that can be used to smartly jump between different wifi signals.

Note: I don't want to use too much 3g because it cost way more then bb. That's why I am looking for something that will jump back to BB the moment it has the internet back.